# Problemas al abrir archivo CSV con PHP

Tags: php, csv

código que uso para abrir el archivo:

```
$tmp_archivo = "file/catalogo.csv";
$archivo = fopen($tmp_archivo, "r");
$row = 0;
if($archivo){
    while ($datos = fgetcsv($archivo, ",")){
        echo utf8_encode($datos[0])."-".utf8_encode($datos[1])."-".utf8_encode($datos[2])."-".utf8_encode($datos[3])."-".utf8_encode($datos[4])."-".utf8_encode($datos[5])."-".utf8_encode($datos[6])."-".utf8_encode($datos[7])."-"."<br>";
}
}
```

Contenido de mi archivo CSV:

```
100010008,Alambre galvanizado Nº 18,KG,,10001,HAWA,Z205,
100010009,Alambre negro recocido Nº 16,KG,COD.ANT.,10001,HAWA,Z205,GRUPO ART. EXT.
100010010,"Alcayata de acero De 2 1/2""",UN,,10001,HAWA,Z205,
```

Resultado que me imprime:

```
100010008-Alambre galvanizado Nº 18-KG--10001-HAWA-Z205-;;;-
100010009-Alambre negro recocido Nº 16-KG-COD.ANT.-10001-HAWA-Z205-GRUPO ART. EXT.;;;-

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11
100010010,"Alcayata de acero De 2 1/2""",UN,,10001,HAWA,Z205,;;;--------
```

La ultima linea la mantiene con las comas, cuando deberían ser reemplazadas por guiones... alguna ayuda? gracias!

Comment: Por desgracia la implementación de [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) no sigue el [rfc4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#page-2). Es decir, aunque selecciones como carácter de escape la comilla (") no convertirá dos comillas dentro de una cadena de caracteres como una comilla real. Por cierto, el segundo parámetro que estás pasando a la función es incorrecto, debería ser el número de caracteres por línea (por defecto 0, sin límite) y no el carácter separador. Tu cadena `"Alcayata de acero De 2 1/2"""` debería convertirse a `Alcayata de acero De 2 1/2"`, pero no funcionará así en PHP.

Comment: @alf, por qué has hecho la pregunta dos veces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun muestras, tu contenido es el siguiente

```
100010008,Alambre galvanizado Nº 18,KG,,10001,HAWA,Z205,
100010009,Alambre negro recocido Nº 16,KG,COD.ANT.,10001,HAWA,Z205,GRUPO ART. EXT.
100010010,"Alcayata de acero De 2 1/2""",UN,,10001,HAWA,Z205,
```

Ahi lo que puedo ibservar es que los dos primeros elementos el nombre esta entre comas (,) pero el ultimo elemento ademas de estar entre comas esta entre comas dobles (") y parece que sobran incluso algunas. Yo probaria de modificar el contenido del archivo .csv a

```
100010008,Alambre galvanizado Nº 18,KG,,10001,HAWA,Z205,
100010009,Alambre negro recocido Nº 16,KG,COD.ANT.,10001,HAWA,Z205,GRUPO ART. EXT.
100010010,Alcayata de acero De 2 1/2,UN,,10001,HAWA,Z205,
```

Siempre manten el mismo estilo en todos los campos. Una vez solventado esto podria ser que ya te funcionara correctamente

Comment: es por las comillas dobles... tengo productos que al final es 2" (2 pulgadas) pero sale lo mismo... tengo que quitarle todas las comillas... gracias